# Normal to a plane

Tags: euclidean-geometry

My textbook makes a quick, unproven claim that if a vector **P** is orthogonal to /one/ vector that lies on a plane G, then **P** is normal to the plane. My question is, is this a mistake? Wouldn't you need **P** to be orthogonal to two vectors on G not contained in the same line, for it to be normal to G?

Thanks!

Comment: It's clearly a mistake. The line $y=z,x=0$ is orthogonal to the $x$-axis but not to the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Thanks Brian. So is my condition correct? That is, for a vector to be normal to a plane it needs to be orthogonal to two vectors on it that aren't on the same line?

Comment: Yes, because if it's normal to $u$ and $v$, then it's normal to everything in the span of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You can post this as an answer if you like, so we can close this question.

Comment: Done!$\qquad\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite right: it's clearly a mistake, since the line $y=z,x=0$ is orthogonal to the $x$-axis but not to the $xy$-plane. Your suggested revision is correct, because if a vector is normal to $u$ and $v$, it's normal to everything in the span of $u$ and $v$.